# Did Hillary collude with Russia?

Tags: united-states, russia, hillary-clinton

On February 18, 2018, the President of the United States of America publicly accused Hillary Clinton of colluding with Russia to change the results of the 2016 election.

> the only Collusion was between Russia and Crooked H(illary Clinton)

[image: Full tweet by Trump says: "General McMaster forgot to say that the results of the 2016 election were not impacted or changed by the Russians and that the only Collusion was between Russia and Crooked H, the DNC and the Dems. Remember the Dirty Dossier, Uranium, Speeches, Emails and the Podesta Company!"]

This [article](https://www.vox.com/world/2018/2/19/17027906/trump-russia-social-media-indictment-lies) calls that claim "bonkers".

Did Hillary Clinton collude with Russia to change the results of the 2016 election with regard to

- the Dirty Dossier,
- <del>Uranium</del> (answered [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/37273/5487)),
- Speeches,
- Emails and
- the Podesta Company?

Comment: "accused Hillary Clinton of colluding with Russia to change the results of the 2016 election." this is not a claim present in the tweet. He actually claims that the results were not changed.

Comment: @viraptor Sure, he doesn't use those exact words, but it seems to me like that's what he's saying. The only story in the news is about collusion to impact the election and that is the topic he's talking about. Then he accuses Crooked H of collusion, what else would she been colluding with Russia about if not the election? Also the question has nothing to do with the result of the collusion, only whether it happened or not.

Comment: Is this really a notable claim? Does anyone actually expect his tweets to be taken seriously?

Comment: @Semaphore Trump still has a large followship of people who actually believe his narrative that he is the victim of a conspiracy between the "mainstream media" and the "deep state". So fact-checking his claims is definitly worth the effort.

Comment: @semaphore Official Statements by the President of the United States are inherently notable.

Comment: There are some specific accusations of collusion in the tweet. Let's restrict the question to those, because the open ended question is a textbook case of Russell's teapot. :-)

Comment: It's also a difficult tweet to address, as it is very vague. She colluded with "speeches"?  You can find a weighing in on what I assume he means by "uranium" https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37273/did-hillary-clinton-give-russia-20-of-the-united-states-uranium

Comment: He is saying the results were not changed.  The claim is that Hillary Clinton's campaign actively worked with Russian actors to create the Steele dossier and spread a narrative of Trump/Russian collusion.  He then mentions other activity unrelated to the election.  "Speeches" in this case would refer to the [paid speeches](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/opinion/commentary/ct-clinton-foundation-investigation-russia-20171120-story.html) that Bill gave while she was Secretary of State.  Emails while SoS.  Uranium and Podesta while SoS.