# Was Hillary Clinton personally involved in approving the Uranium One purchase?

Tags: united-states, politics, hillary-clinton

In 2013, a Russian company bought a Canadian company called Uranium One which owns a uranium mine in the United States.  This purchase was approved by the US government through an interagency review process which included State Department.  In any case, [here](https://www.wmur.com/article/hillary-clinton-facing-questions-over-involvement-in-uranium-one-sale/5201352) is what former Secretary of State Hillary Clinton told WMUR in 2015, in response to Republican allegations that she approved the purchase due to donations the Clinton Foundation had received:

> There's no basis for any of that. The timing doesn't work. It happened in terms of the work for the foundation before I was secretary of state.   There were nine government agencies that that had to sign off on that deal. **I was not personally involved because that’s not something (the) secretary of state did.**

My question is, is Secretary Clinton right that she was not personally involved in the approval of the purchase of Uranium One?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Are you sure that your question is different enough from this one: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37273/did-hillary-clinton-give-russia-20-of-the-united-states-uranium/ ?

Comment: @defaultlocale Well, that’s more of a complex claim.  Because regardless of what Hillary’s role was, I’d argue that it’s simply false that anyone gave 20% of America’s uranium to Russia.  A Russian company bought a Canadian company which owns an American mine which has no export license.  So it’s not like Russia could use this purchase to take uranium out of America.  Whereas this is a straightforward question about Hillary’s involvement in a very specific decision.

Comment: @defaultlocale In any case, the answer to that question does touch on what I asked, but it just says “Clinton has denied that she was involved, and the consensus seems to be that the Secretary would mostly likely not be involved in the details.” without backing it up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, she was not involved.**. The purchase of Uranium One was approved by an interagency panel called the Committee on Foreign Investment in the United States.  [Here](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/04/24/us/cash-flowed-to-clinton-foundation-as-russians-pressed-for-control-of-uranium-company.html?_r=0) is what former Assistant Secretary of State Jose Fernandez, who was the State Department representative on this committee at the time of the Uranium One purchase approval, told the New York Times in 2015:

> Mrs. Clinton never intervened with me on any C.F.I.U.S. matter.

It follows that she did not intervene with him on approving the purchase of Uranium One.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102174/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-was-hillary-clinton-personally-involve).